# What to do about incorrect use of "webmathematica" tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [webmathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webmathematica) tag is for questions about [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/).  I noticed that recently new members keep adding this tag to questions unrelated to webMathematica, for no apparent reason.  I just removed a few such tags, but then decided to leave the rest so you can see what I mean.

My guess is that people use this tag when they are using [Mathematica Online](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/online/) (I'm almost certain).

**The question:** What can we do to avoid the incorrect use of this tag?  When people are using Mathematica Online, and they look for a corresponding tag, many will inevitably search for "web", which brings up [webmathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webmathematica) but not [mathematica-online](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica-online).

What would be a practical solution to this problem?  How can we make sure that these two different technologies won't end up using the same tag on this site?

---

**Update**

Karsten's suggestion is that:

1. We should use [wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud) as the main tag for thing like Mathematica Online and the Programming Cloud
2. We should have a synonym for this which has the word `web` in it. This way when people type "web", the appropriate tag suggestion will come up (in addition to [webmathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webmathematica)

Please vote on the answers do decide which one(s) we should have as synonyms for [wolfram-cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-cloud).

Suggestions for alternative resolutions are still welcome!

Comment: As a first move I changed the wiki excerpt for the tag to **For all questions relating to webMathematica.  Not for questions relating to Mathematica Online.**  I cannot think of a better approach.

Comment: Did you create the [tag:mathematica-online] tag recently? I think it should become a synonym for [tag:wolfram-cloud], because of [this meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1680/18476). Having [tag warnings](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1736/18476) would be most useful for this situation.

Comment: @Karsten7. I didn't create it.  `wolfram-cloud` sounds good.  One little caveat is that there's using Mathematica in the web browser and there's `CloudEvaluate`, which are related but different uses.  If both have the same tag, personally I wouldn't mind about that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating the tag synonym [mathematica-in-webbrowser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematica-in-webbrowser) to solve this problem.

Comment: Just noting that the tag size limit is 25 characters, and so far all suggestions fit in this limit (this is is exactly 25 characters long).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating the tag synonym [webbrowser-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webbrowser-mathematica) to solve this problem.

Comment: You mean that these would map to `wolfram-cloud`, right?  How about `web-interface-mathematica`?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I think these should map to `wolfram-cloud`, as `mathematica-online` should be a synonym for `wolfram-cloud`. (I can neither create nor suggest synonyms for that tag on [its tag info page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/wolfram-cloud/synonyms).) I'm fine with `web-interface-mathematica`, too. You may want to make that an additional answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating the tag synonym `web-interface-mathematica` to solve this problem.